# Does spark behave like a library?

Tags: apache-spark

When writing an Application in Scala using Spark, when ran, is it a regular Scala application which "delegates the spark jobs to the spark cluster" and gets the desired results back ?

Or does it get completely compiled to something special consumed by a "spark engine" ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the "deploy mode"

If you use local mode, then all actions occur locally, and you don't get any benefits from distribution that Spark is meant for. While it can be used to abstract different libraries and provide clean ways to process data via dataframes or ML, it's not really intended to be used like that

Instead, you can use cluster mode, in which your app just defines the steps to take, and then when submitted, everything happens in the remote cluster. In order to process data back in the driver, you need to use methods such as `collect()`, or otherwise download the results from remote file systems/databases